# Nearby Connections advertise with application context

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby

I'm using [Nearby Connections framework](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) for Quiz Game application. Also, I'm using MVVM design pattern along with live data and room. When I call `Nearby.getConnectionsClient()` in activity, I can pass `this` as argument or `applicationContext` as argument and everything works. But I don't want handle networking in activity, I want do this for example in view model (or maybe some singleton). But when I use `AndroidViewModel(application)` and as argument pass `application.applicationContext`, which is same application context like in activity, it doesn't work. When I'm trying to advertise, I get `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: ERROR`. I have no idea what is difference and why this is not working. Plus when I am using activity context and rotate a phone, it got destroyed. So I need start advertising again?

I'm working on quiz app and I want to create lobby activity, where you can find nearby HOSTS and join. Then I want to have access to this connection in next activities, where game is playing. So also I don't have idea how to work with this connection in multiple activities.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the application context definitely works. Try using the application object itself instead of Application.applicationContext

Comment: `application` and `application.applicationContext` are working the same way. I found a problem when it's not working, but I don't know why. I was calling my `startAdvertise()` method in `init { }` of my AndroidViewModel class. It's always a failure. If I called `startAdvertise` later, for example on tap of a button, it works and starts advertising. Problem is, I need to call it when I enter in activity, so when view model is created.